# SpriteKit: Determine drawing order for hit test

Tags: sprite-kit, hittest, skeffectnode, skcropnode

i am using Spritekit and want to have a hit test, that works intuitive.
In other words: I got a position x,y and want to to find out which is the top most node that was hit. (And with "top most" i mean the one that the user actually sees as topmost.)

I did not find any predefined functionality of SpriteKit that gives me this functionality.
Actually i found that SpriteKit itself uses some counter intuitive hit testing, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245494/in-spritekit-how-is-zposition-used-for-rendering-and-for-hit-tests).

My idea to implement this by myself is to calculate some global z ordering, like described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709235/spritekit-not-respecting-zposition), by Dobroćudni Tapir.

I think this may work, what confuses me is the statement in the documentation:

> Important: The SKCropNode and SKEffectNode node classes alter the scene rendering behavior. The children of these nodes are rendered independently as a separate node tree, and the results are rendered into the tree that contains the crop or effect node. For more information, see Working with Other Node Types.

To find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html), beneath "Understanding the Drawing Order for a Node Tree".

I did not find the referred "Working with Other Node Types" point, so i have no idea how and why SKCropNodes or SKEffectNodes should change the drawing order ...

So answers to the following questions could help me:

- Does SpriteKit offer some functionality to retrieve the drawing oder?
- If not, do you think that my custom implementation work? (How could Crop or Effect nodes destroy it?)
- Could you point me to information regarding this question? Like the missing "Working with other nodes" article?

**Update:**

I just found out that the behaviour reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245494/in-spritekit-how-is-zposition-used-for-rendering-and-for-hit-tests) is not correct.

As mentioned in the comments i was pointed to nodeAtPosition or nodesAtPosition. I used the code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245494/in-spritekit-how-is-zposition-used-for-rendering-and-for-hit-tests) and tested it.

The result is not satisfying. Two problems:

1. The set zPosition is ignored in nodesAtPosition. Independent if blue or red square is in front i get the same order in the array returned in nodesAtPosition.
2. These functions use the accumulated frame. But in a prefect case i would like to use the exact size of each node and not the accumulated frame.

Some pictures to 1. :
[image]

[image]

Comment: The SK Programming Guide explicitly states that hit testing is done in reverse draw order.  That seems to be both what you want and well defined.

Comment: Do you have any references for that? What i have found suggested that this is not the case, [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245494/in-spritekit-how-is-zposition-used-for-rendering-and-for-hit-tests).

And if i am wrong here. Can you point a function in SpriteKit where i can perform a hit test explicitly for a position?

Comment: To what end is this critical for your code logic?

Comment: The point is that i get events from hardware that i need to process into the scene. At this point i need to decide to which of the nodes i refer the event. Therefore i need to now which node is at position x,y at the top of the drawing order. The Problem is i did not find anything to get this draw order or to ask SpriteKit something like "which is top node at position x,y"

Comment: @NieLernend See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html) (search for section entitled **The Hit-Testing Order Is the Reverse of Drawing Order**).

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for the hint. I tested both of these functions and found two problems. Updated my question.